# docker build stopped at 67c44324f4e3: Downloading 8.633 MB

Tags: docker, sinopia

I was trying to docker build [docker-sinopia](https://github.com/kfatehi/docker-sinopia). then it stopped at 67c44324f4e3: Downloading 8.633 MB. What should I do now

Comment: Your internet connection dropped. Restart it.

Comment: I don't think so, I tried several times and I'm sure my network is ok